# Rust инициализация структуры как Arc

Tags: rust

Есть очередь:

```
pub struct Queue {
  data: std::collections::VecDeque<u8>,
}
```

Пытаюсь инициализировать её как Arc:

```
let mut input_bufer = Arc::<Queue>{
    data: std::collections::VecDeque::new()
};
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
error[E0560]: struct `std::sync::Arc<Queue>` has no field named `data`
  --> src\main.rs:55:9
   |
55 |         data: std::collections::VecDeque::new()
   |         ^^^^ `std::sync::Arc<Queue>` does not have this field
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=613e390ad80ca004c38c7570dcfb50db

Comment: Вроде ж согласно документации по Arc надо `Arc::new(Queue {data: std::collections::VecDeque::new()})`?

Comment: Да, действительно, не дошло до меня это. Спасибо большое!